# Can one say [ゲームを遊ぶ ]?

Tags: grammar, word-choice

So I know that commonly people say 「ゲームをする」or 「NOUNで遊ぶ」 yet on the　Japanese playstation website, I see 「ゲームを遊ぶ」written, even though the verb is intransitive. Are they both correct or is it sorta like an Incorrect usage but commonly understood, like some english phrases?

Comment: Related: [How do you express that you are playing a game?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/61586/5010)

Comment: How would an intransitive verb take an object, though? Is it just an exception?

Comment: Yes, that's the point of your question, and the link does not answer that part. For now, I would say 遊ぶ also has a transitive usage.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think ゲームを遊ぶ and ゲームで遊ぶ are both perfectly correct. Although some dictionaries say 遊ぶ is only intransitive, you can find some transitive usages of 遊ぶ on BCCWJ, including:

- ゲームを遊ぶ
- マリオを遊ぶ
- 月を愛で歌を詠み、御座の間などでも花を遊ぶ
- 何を遊ぶかということではなくて、どのように遊ぶか
- 渋谷の夜を遊ぶ
- ホノルルを遊ぶ (although this を may be taken as [a location marker](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/3243/5010))

The difference is usually subtle and unimportant, but ゲームを遊ぶ sounds like ゲーム is the main purpose, whereas ゲームで遊ぶ sounds like ゲーム is just a method to have fun. The following article intentionally distinguishes ゲームを遊ぶ and ゲームで遊ぶ:

- [｢ニンテンドースイッチ｣レビュー：”ゲームを遊ぶ”と”ゲームで遊ぶ”。2種類の遊び方をスイッチできるゲームハードの究極進化系](https://www.gizmodo.jp/2017/03/nintendo-switch-review.html)